# Multiple returns: Which one sets the final return value?

Tags: java, return, finally

Given this code:

```
String test() {
    try {
        return "1";
    } finally {
        return "2";
    }
}
```

Do the language specifications define the return value of a call to `test()`? In other words: Is it always the same in every JVM?

In the Sun JVM the return value is `2`, but I want to be sure, that this is not VM-dependant.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Yes, the [language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2) defines that "2" is the result. If a VM does it differently, it's not spec-compliant.

Most compilers will complain about it. Eclipse, for example, will claim that the return block will never be executed, but it's wrong.

It's shockingly bad practice to write code like that, don't ever do it :)

Comment: *don't ever do it*, apparently college professors really LOVE writing code like this, although its been 10 years since your answer

Answer (score 21):

Yes, the *Java Language Specification* is very clear on this issue ([14.20.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2)):

> **A try statement with a finally block is executed by first executing the try block. Then there is a choice:**
>
> - If execution of the try block completes normally, [...]
> - If execution of the try block completes abruptly because of a throw of a value V, [...]
> - **If execution of the try block completes abruptly for any other reason R, then the finally block is executed. Then there is a choice:**
>
>   - If the finally block completes normally, [...]
>   - **If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason S (and reason R is discarded).**

Answer (score 20):

The finally block will always be executed except in the following example:

```
String test() {
    try {
        System.exit(0);
    } finally {
        return "2";
    }
}
```

In this case, the JVM will stop, without executing the `finally` block.

So in your example, the return value will be `2`.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, if you return something from the `finally` block, it will replace whatever you might have returned from the `try` or `catch` block.

The same is true also for *exceptions*. If you throw something in the `finally` block, that exception will replace whatever exception was thrown in the `try` or `catch` block. So be careful to never throw something in the `finally` block, because it may hide the original reason for a failure.

Comment: another interesting thing is that if something is returned from finally using `return` then any thrown exception is discarded.

Answer (score 5):

After reading the ByteCode of program, the code is as follows:

The finally block statements is inlined before the return statement of try block, so the return from the finally block executes first and the original return statement never does.

**For Program:**

```
String test() {
        try {
            System.out.println("try");
            return "1";
        } finally {
            System.out.println("finally");
            return "2";
        }
    }
```

It converts to:

```
String test()
    {
        System.out.println("try");
        String s = "1"; //temporary variable 
        System.out.println("finally");
        return "2";
        Exception exception;
        exception;
        System.out.println("finally");
        return "2";
    }
```

And **For program:** with catch block:

```
String test() {

        try {
            System.out.println("try");
            return "1";
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println("catch");
            return "2";
        } finally {
            System.out.println("finally");
            return "3";
        }
    }
```

Converts to:

```
String test()
    {
        System.out.println("try");
        String s = "1";
        System.out.println("finally");
        return "3";
        RuntimeException e;
        e;
        System.out.println("catch");
        String s1 = "2";
        System.out.println("finally");
        return "3";
        Exception exception;
        exception;
        System.out.println("finally");
        return "3";
    }
```

*Note: Complied using JDK 1.7 & Decompiled using Cavaj.*

Comment: 'throw e'  will never be reachable.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the below link. I hope it will provide all details:

http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/will-finally-run-after-return/

It says finally block will always executes even try or catch block has return statement. And if finally block also has return statement then this will override the return statement which is inside try or catch block and in this case any exception thrown in try/catch will be discarded (bad approach).

Answer (score 0):

Above answer's is very well summarized just want to add one more point here.

```
private static int divide(int a , int b){
    try{
        return  a/b;
    }finally{
        System.out.println("In finally");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

If we pass the 1,0 then the above method will suppress the exception thrown by it and just return the result.
Been said, the above code should not be used in production environment.

```
  private static int divide(int a , int b){
        int result = 0;
        try{
            result =   a/b;
        }finally{
            System.out.println("In finally");
            result =  1;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

using the return statement after the finally block will result in

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```