# Why can't control leave a finally statement?

Tags: c#, try-catch

When I place a `return` inside the block of a `finally` statement, the compiler tells me:

> Control cannot leave the body of a finally clause

Example:

```
try
{
}
catch
{
}
finally
{
    return;
}
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Consider what would happen if you were to `return 1` inside the `try` block and `return 0` inside the `finally` block... Your function would be trying to return two values! The combined options of `try` and `catch` are exhaustive in terms of control flow.

Comment: Works in Java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309964/multiple-returns-which-one-sets-the-final-return-value

Answer (score 27):

It's by design and it's described in C# specification:

> It is a compile-time error for a `break`, `continue`, or `goto` statement to
>   transfer control out of a `finally` block. When a `break`, `continue`, or
>   `goto` statement occurs in a `finally` block, the target of the statement
>   must be within the same `finally` block, or otherwise a compile-time
>   error occurs.
>
> **It is a compile-time error for a `return` statement to
>   occur in a `finally` block**.

Also, from [C# 6.0 spec draft on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-try-statement):

> It is a compile-time error for a `return` statement to occur in a `finally` block.

Comment: Your link is rotten, but I couldn't find the new version.

Comment: @ANeves I couldn't either. The spec ships with every Visual Studio, so the quote is still valid, just not the link. I added a new one to C# 6.0 spec draft, which has the same statement.

Answer (score -10):

Current answers explain why this happens well, but I also think it's important to note how easy it is to circumvent this constraint **in the case where no return value is involved, and the `finally` clause is the last thing in the method** (which happens often):

```
try {}
catch {}
finally
{
    FinallyMethod();
}
```

Then in `FinallyMethod` you can use `return` statements as much as you'd like

```
void FinallyMethod()
{
   //...
   if (x == y)
       return;
   else
       a = b;
   //etc.
}
```

Comment: Returning inside `FinallyMethod` won't do anything for the method containing the try/catch/finally.

Comment: Just because you `return` from `FinallyMethod` won't make you return from the calling site.

Comment: Of course, but it can be useful for control flow, e.g. `if (!x) return; //do a lot of stuff`. So you can use `return` in `FinallyMethod` for that purpose instead of doing everything under nested `if` clauses.

Comment: OK, I understand now what you mean now. But it's not really relevant to the example in the question, because you wouldn't be using `return` in the `finally` block to begin with, when using your example.

Comment: @Stijn I agree it's not fully relevant, just a tip in case the last thing in your method is the `finally` clause (which very often is the case) and then using the method I suggested is equivalent to using `return`. I've clarified that in my answer.