# Exception in try with resources clause

Tags: java, ioexception, try-with-resources

```
class Demo
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException
    {
        try(FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("Demo.txt"))
        {
            //This block is executed successfully
        }
        
        System.out.println("Will it be executed if error occurs in try clause");
    }
}
```

Suppose that the code in `try block` is executed successfully as mentioned in the code, and some `exception` occurs in `try with resource clause`, that means exception occurs in `auto closing` of file.

#### How that exception in the `try with resource clause` will be handled?

What I want to ask is that will that exception be thrown to JVM and will terminate my program abruptly and the `println` statement will not be executed?

Can I catch that exception so that remaining program can also be executed?

Comment: Why don't you simply try it yourself?

Comment: A ```finally``` clause make work here

Comment: @Turing85 : I don't know how to make the `try with resources clause` throw an exception.

Comment: Yes, the exception will be thrown to JVM and will terminate my program if you don't catch it

Comment: @ValentinRuano : I also guessed that, but is there any alternate solution. Because the code after `try block` may be huge, so putting the entire code in `finally block` is not appreciable.

Comment: @kevingomes Simply create a class that implements `AutoCloseable` using that in a try-with-resources statement. You can let the `close` method throw an exception.

Comment: @SafwanHijazi : Can I catch that by adding a `catch clause` after try block.

Comment: @kevingomes yes sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

only add catch clause, to catch the exception otherwise program will be terminated

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        try(FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("Demo.txt"))
        {
            //This block is executed successfully
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Will it be executed if error occurs in try clause");
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

If an exception is thrown by the `close` method of an `AutoClosable` it will indeed be thrown after the `try` block has been executed.

If you need to handle the exception you can simply add a catch clause to your try clause.

The following code illustrates the behavior:

```
public class Foo {

    public static class Bar implements AutoCloseable {

        @Override
        public void close() {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try (Bar b = new Bar()) {
            // This block is executed successfully
        }

        System.out.println("Will it be executed if error occurs in try clause");
    }
}
```

It terminates the JVM with the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException
at test3.Foo$Bar.close(Foo.java:14)
at test3.Foo.main(Foo.java:25)
```

25 is the line where the closing `}` for my `try` clause is.

It could be handled by using:

```
try (Bar b = new Bar()) {
    // This block is executed successfully
} catch (Exception e) {
     // ...
}
```

Comment: You do not need the outer `try`.

Answer (score 1):

I think with a finally the rest of the program will be run, please try it and report.

class Demo

```
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException
    {
        try(FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("Demo.txt"))
        {
            //This block is executed successfully
        } finally {
           System.out.println("Will it be executed if error occurs in try clause");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it work. And I have already guessed this idea. But if the code after `try block` is huge then putting a huge code in `finally block` is not appreciable.

Comment: You should be careful with `finally`-blocks. `finally` is always executed, [which can lead to funny behaviours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/does-finally-always-execute-in-java). `finally` should be use for some cleanup, that needs to be done and using it for another purpose may lead to unwanted results.

Comment: @kevingomes you can always extract the code into its own method.

Comment: @Turing85, I have to agree with you in part, in a more complex example a specific catch is advisable in order to do a more specific treatment to the problem, for the current example I think the finally suffices though. Don't understand the "funny" part of "funny behaviours", finally's behaviour is quite robust even if it might not be appropriate for the situation. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @ValentinRuano [look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309964/multiple-returns-which-one-sets-the-final-return-value) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/65362/4216641).

Comment: @Turing85, still don't see it what the "funny" behaviour is. It is well defined in the language spec; returns or throws in the finally override the result of the try bloc. My understanding of funny behavior is for example the unpredictable effect of accessing a non-thread safe collection from different threads simultaneously.

Comment: @ValentinRuano I did not say that is is not well-defined, only "funny" in the sense of "unexpected" or "not blatantly obvious".

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the file Demo.txt and run the following code.

The simplest way to throw such exception is to run this code, with no existing resource (Demo.txt in this case):

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try(FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("Demo.txt"))
        {

        } catch(IOException exc) {
            System.out.println("An exception has occured. Possibly, the file does not exist. " + exc);
        }

        System.out.println("Will it be executed if error occurs in try clause");
    }
```